# How can I overcome table/view exclusion from entity data model when no primary key is available or can not be inferred?

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework-4

I have an EF data model that I have updated from a number of views on an existing database.

There is one such view where a primary key didn't exist nor could one be inferred and subsequently is excluded when trying to update the model.

Unfortunately, I can't update the schema for the view I'm trying to use. I am just wondering what the best course of action would be to be able to add this entity to my model. I only infact need two columns from the view itself.

I may be able to create a stored procedure to return a result set, but just wondering if there was any other method before I pursue this avenue.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like you are on the right path.  Entity Framework is picky on the primary keys.

Comment: Go code first (maybe after a jump start with [EF Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d)). Maximum control! You must be 100% sure though that your view rows can be uniquely identified by EF, otherwise you will get duplicates in the result set.

Comment: @Gert Arnold, Thanks, but in this case I'm working with a database that already existed, not one that I can necessarily make changes to existing database objects either. I potentially have the ability to create new stored procs, that is it. I was hoping there might be something within EF that would enabled me to work around the problem  given in the question.

Comment: Sure, but you can work code first with an existing database (some call it code second).

Comment: Ah right, could this 'code second' solve my problem though if I'm trying to retrieve data from the view that exists yet can't load into my data model? Sorry, I'm just trying to understand

Comment: You can create a POCO class yourself and map it to the view. See _Programming Entity Framework: Code First_ by Lerman and Miller.